# Data export view gives error if 0 records

Tags: importing-exporting

I have a data export option on a view.  however , if the filter has not chosen any records, the excel export gives an error.  Is there anyway to disable the data export icon if no records have been chosen, or other wise avoid this error?

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a bugreport, and bugreports belongs to issue queue, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been transitioned to https://www.drupal.org/node/2576429 per the request of Mołot.